# gitlab-runner docker: command not found

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to build docker container using GitLab runner.
(lead dev left company, and now I have no idea how to do it.)

I'll share everything I can.

Build output
[image: output error]

as I understand from output runner is assigned correctly, the problem is with docker

***the runner is running as Shell executor***

here is **.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  STACK_NAME: isnta_api
  VERSION: ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}
  IMAGE_NAME: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}

before_script:
  - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --password-stdin
  - echo $STACK_NAME
  - echo $CI_REGISTRY
  - echo $IMAGE_NAME

build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - docker build -f Dockerfile -t ${IMAGE_NAME}  .
    - docker push ${IMAGE_NAME}

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file docker-compose.yml ${STACK_NAME}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    container_name: ${STACK_NAME}
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
    environment:
      PORT: 4042
      APP_ENV: production
      INSTAGRAM_API_KEY: my-api-key
      INSTAGRAM_API_HOST_NAME: instagram-bulk-profile-scrapper.p.rapidapi.com
      INSTAGRAM_API_BASE_URL: https://instagram-bulk-profile-scrapper.p.rapidapi.com/clients/api/ig/
    networks:
      - nxnet
    ports:
      - 4042:4042
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        order: start-first

networks:
  nxnet:
    external: true
```

and **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

CMD npm run start:prod
```

Any suggestions or tips would be valuable. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your Gitlab Runner does not have the capabilities to run Docker commands.

To enable your Gitlab Runner to run Docker commands you can:

1. Modify your Gitlab Runner to use the [Docker Executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html)
2. Use one of the approaches in this [document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) to enable docker commands in your existing Gitlab runner

Comment: #2 worked perfectly, installed gitlab-runner, granted docker permissions, and it worked. Thank you.